# Pulling Previous week based upon getdate

Tags: sql

I am looking to sum last weeks sales based upon the getdate. I need to look at today's date and which is in week 24 and sum all sales for week 23 which is the previous week.  I am looking to do this dynamically based upon the getdate()

Answer (score 0):

Below query will help you

```
DECLARE @CurrentDate datetime,
        @CurrentWeekFrom datetime,
        @LastWeekFrom datetime,
        @LastWeekEnd datetime

SET @CurrentDate = GetDate()
SET @CurrentWeekFrom = DateAdd(wk, DateDiff(wk, 0, @CurrentDate), 0)  
SET @LastWeekFrom = DateAdd(wk, -1, @CurrentWeekFrom)
SET @LastWeekEnd = DateAdd(dd, -1, @LastWeekFrom)

SELECT SUM(Sales) AS Sales FROM table1
               Where SalesDate Between  @LastWeekFrom And @LastWeekEnd
```